# Multiple bib references in the same footnote with the opcit package

Tags: footnotes

I am new to LaTeX and I am hoping to use it in the field of the humanities. I have a problem when I try to add multiple bibliographic references in the same footnote using the opcit package. It seems to be working with one reference only. When I add two others `\cite{Gerbier2003,Parel1992,Gaille2003}` the result is an empty footnote. No error message appear in the console. I am using XeTeX with the polyglossia, fontspec and babelbib packages.

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You might consider using `biblatex`: it has a `\footcites` command and it can be customised.